# RelativeSource TemplatedParent

Tags: wpf, data-binding

If I Have this template

```
<DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=SomePath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

and this template

```
<DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=Source.SomePath, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

From the point of performance, is there a significant difference between the two?

Lets assume that this template is used in a Grid Control cell, so there will be multiple instances of TextBlocks (cells) displayed.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), TemplatedParent enumeration will resolve to a static value, which in my opinion means that it will resolve only once for all cells. This should mean that the difference between the two methods should be very little, performance wise.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Why not profile first? Also: If i recall correctly `TemplatedParent` only applies to `ControlTemplates`.

Comment: the 2 codes seem to be different to me, the first code binds `Visibility` to the `SomePath` property of the TempatedParent control while the second code binds `Visibility` to the `Source.SomePath` whereas `Source` is the property of the underlying (databound) item. Have you tried both the codes? Do they work the same? weird.

Comment: @KingKing Just imagine the Source property to point to a TemplatedParent control, and it will not be weird eny more. The question is related to costs of TemplatedBinding vs "direct" Binding.

Comment: @Goran not sure, you should follow the instruction of *H.B*, he mentioned about **profile**, that's the simplest way to go. Try creating 2 simple demos and you'll get the answer.  I guess that you have not even created any demo yet. Also if you try it, I would like to know the result.

Comment: @KingKing I have never profiled WPF UI before. The project already exists, but although you cannot notice any difference in work, that is not a sign that they perform the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is almost correct but not quite.

Given that the template is used in a `Grid` Template and that `DataTemplate` is being used multiple times then it will only resolve it once based on the parent template that you are customizing but if the value for `SomePath` changes, the number of cells that have this template ***will do N calls to the TemplateParent's Value.***

Assuming `Source` is the `DataContext` of your Grid, doing so will result to multiple calls which is exactly the same as the `TemplateBinding`. Same thing applies when the underlying value changes

**Conclusion**: In my experience, there is no significant performance difference between the two because they are the same number of calls depending on how it is being used like binding's *mode, updatesourcetrigger, etc.*

`TemplateBinding` is usually used for when you are creating custom controls that have custom `DependencyProperties` of your own with corresponding`ControlTemplates`. So they are handy if you want the child controls to inherit the value from the parent.

Your second example can be interpreted as this control is just bound to a `ViewModel` and saying that *"Hey, I know that the child control needs to be bound to a property in the ViewModel called `SomePath`."* and can't be used with other `ViewModel`

Comment: WHat I was trying to get here is how much penalties does TemplatedParent takes. The Source object in this case should be equal to TemplatedParent, so that both DataTemplates would resolve in the same object. I was only trying to compare the direct binding to Source, vs using TemplastedParent, considering that both bindings will resolve at the same object.

Comment: @Goran I just looked at the internals, they all boil down to getting `GetObject` method which does the same thing. So my conclusion is still no significant performance difference. Since it is inside a binding expression too the expression should be parsed the same too.